# How to enforce documentation of private methods in StyleCop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, stylecop

Our team has some code guidelines that I would like to enforce via stylecop rules. For most of the things a Settings.Stylecop file is used. However, I would like to enforce documentation for private methods and I can not find the way to do this in the Settings file. If I right-click on a project and select "stylecop settings", I can uncheck "Ignore privates" under "Documentation Rules" and that would achieve my goal, but I can not figure out how to enforce this rule solution-wise and most importantly, this setting is not saved to Settings.Stylecop file.

So, the two questions are:

1. How to enforce documentation for private methods on a solution basis so that it could be shared with the team?
2. Where the project-wise settings (ones that override the settings file) are stored?

Comment: I use StyleCop with the default settings and it does give me warnings for undocumented private methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Settings.StyleCop:

Under AnalyzerSettings:

```
    <BooleanProperty Name="IgnorePrivates">False</BooleanProperty>
```

Sorry for being stupid.

I still wonder, though, where the project-wise overrides are stored.